# FBLoginView crashes when user has an account in Settings>Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook

Im using facebookSDK FbLoginView, after I select ok on allowing access of basic profile info and friends list. It crashes then passes on this part

```
else if (errorCategory == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
        // The user has cancelled a login. You can inspect the error
        // for more context. For this sample, we will simply ignore it.
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
        NSLog(@"user cancelled login");
    }
```

I receive this log.

> 2013-11-30 13:42:54.000 OreoTime[1628:70b] The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.) 2013-11-30 13:42:54.000
>   OreoTime[1628:70b] user cancelled login

This only happens when the user has an acccount logged in in Settings>Facebook, but when not it works fine.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also faced this issue. I solved this after editting the Facebook App setting in Facebook Developer portal.

enable the Native iOS App option and Add app bundle identifier there.

I am attaching a screenShot for more details.

Screenshot
[image]

If You want to remove the Native iOS App then you have to Read the [Facebook Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login/)

According to Facebook:

> The Facebook SDK automatically selects the optimal login dialog flow
>   based on the account settings and capabilities of a person's device.
>   This is the default sequence that the Facebook SDK implements:
>
> iOS Login Dialog
>
> Facebook App Native Login Dialog
>
> Facebook App Web Login Dialog
>
> Mobile Safari Login Dialog